# cant remove html entities in php

Tags: php, html, string, entities

Good morning everyone,

I try to "clean" a string with html entities in php but its not working :-/.

Here is my simple code example:

```
$body = "Mal ein neuer &amp;lt;b&amp;gt;Test&amp;lt;/b&amp;gt;&amp;lt;br&amp;gt;";
$body = html_entity_decode($body);
$body = strip_tags($body);

var_dump($body);
```

The Output is:

```
string(47) "Mal ein neuer <b>Test</b><br>"
```

Someone have an idea that my result ist just "Mal ein neuer Test"?

best regards,
Niklas

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Have you checked what `$body` contains after the first call of `html_entity_decode`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two levels of encoding in the original string. `<b>` was encoded into `&lt;b&gt;`, and then this was encoded into `&amp;lt;b&amp;gt;`

So you need to decode it twice before you can strip the tags.

```
$body = "Mal ein neuer &amp;lt;b&amp;gt;Test&amp;lt;/b&amp;gt;&amp;lt;br&amp;gt;";
$body = html_entity_decode($body);
$body = html_entity_decode($body);
$body = strip_tags($body);
var_dump($body);
```

Comment: thanks alot for the fast answer. You solved my problem :)